# oauth2-server-php no creatin tokens.

Tags: php, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to configure oauth from https://github.com/bshaffer/oauth2-server-php
I followed the step by step guide and wanted to create a token. 
However a token is not created and i can't find the error. I'm calling it with.

```
curl -u testclient:testpass http://tblocal:8888/token.php -d 'grant_type=client_credentials'
```

I already checked the following things.
1.) The Connection to the database works. If I change the credentials I get an error.
2.) The files (token.php, and server.php) are loaded properly. They are both in the same directory and manipulating them (adding errors) results in en error when calling curl.
3.) I have rechecked several times that the user is in the database.

I tried different users which are not in the db and the result is the same... So it seems that the database is not accesed properly. However I do not know how I could debug this issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have this line in your `server.php`?
`$server->addGrantType(new OAuth2\GrantType\ClientCredentials($storage));`